# Add new field in SOLR does not show up

Tags: sdl-tridion, solr

I have an existing field "Link_URL" in SDL Tridion schema. Now I added this field in solr "schema.xml" for indexing. But It doesn't show up in the solr response.

I restarted Solr, TRIDION. But it does not work. Can someone tell me what part of the configuration am I missing or please provide the steps.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange. Can you please share your schema.xml entry for the Link_URL and also share the version of the Tridion .

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the [link](http://80000ft.blogspot.com/2012/08/search-indexing-handlers.html) on how to add a custom field on solr and implement Search Indexing Handler and add it to the content manager configuration.

In your case

```
<field name="Link_URL_dyn_s_str" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

Not sure what is your requirement to add the field Link_URL to solr, you can save the search folder mentioned in the document and get the records

If you want to search index to have the data of new field, you need to remove the existing collection and create a new collection , example

stop the search indexer and  search host service , go to the tridion install folder / Search/solr-data/tridion ( rename the folder) and start the service again to generate new search collection and try to run the search folder again on CMS to view the results.

Comment: A very timely question, Anand!

Comment: Yes Neil I agree

Comment: yes when you access http://servername:8983/#/tridion/query  and select wt option ( xml or json) you can ( access the URL using ) http://server:8983/tridion/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true , Not sure you are asking question or you are saying you are able to see the data , please clarify

Comment: Thanks. Let me explain clearly. We have Tridion in one server(A) and Solr in another server(B). If we publish a page in Tridion, those data are passed to Solr. If we hit Solr query in browser(http://<ipaddress>/select?<querystrings> ), we can see those data in JSON format. My need is , I added a new field in the Tridion page then published it. In Solr side, in schema.xml I added the new field. I restarted Solr service, tridion search indexer and search host service. Still I am not getting the new field in Solr search output. What configuration part I am missing?

Comment: refer to this link m when you add a new field , you need to extend the SearchIndexer and perform re-index by removing old collection and generate new collection so the value of the field that you have gets added to the the search collection, you need to implement the handler to achieve this.

Comment: When you say you added a field to the page , is this field part of the page metadata? please provide more details where is this field that you  associated to page is part of ??

Comment: No, its not page metadata field. Its a General field for the page.

Comment: Is there any article or doc for the handler implementation?

Comment: Refer to this link - http://80000ft.blogspot.com/2012/08/search-indexing-handlers.html