# Tridion and SOLR Configuration

Tags: configuration, solr

Hi I am using Tridion CMS and have configuration with SOLR, however, I would like to add new fields. I have added new fields in Tridion, but they are not being configured properly in SOLR, is there a step that I might be missing when configuring the new fields?

If possible, is there a walkthrough of the necessary steps to make sure that the new fields are being configured between Tridion and SOLR properly?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange. Please share Tridion version and when you say you added new field on Tridion and what type and  did you try to extend the default field provided with solr configurtion and you don’t know how to do . Pls provide what you are trying to achieve so we can answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21511/add-new-field-in-solr-does-not-show-up)  recent post on how to add a new field on SOLR.

Comment: Thank you Anand. I am using SDL Web 8. I will check out the link that you sent now.

Comment: Hi Anand, I have attempted the solution that you have referenced, but it did not work. Do you have the capacity to walk me through the steps sometimes this week 1 on 1? Thank you, Sam